# serverless-dynamodb-local web shell error

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless-plugins

First time trying out serverless framework.
Am trying to use the local web shell to do some inspection.
But realise I couldn't list tables or show a list of records.

**Web shell example:**

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'stocks-table-dev',
};
dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response
});
```

The above command throws a status code `413` error.

[image]

But `aws cli` works fine: `aws dynamodb scan --table-name=stocks-table-dev --endpoint-url='http://localhost:8000'`

I start the web shell with the command `sls dynamodb start`.
Prior to that, I used the following commands to install the plugin:

- `npm install --save-dev serverless-dynamodb-local`
- `sls dynamodb install`

Am I suppose to use the web shell for inspection?
Is there some configuration to be done for the web shell to work?

Comment: After you start the dynamodb local, can you check whether the web shell is running?